# Order in ggplot2 grouped barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is my code:

```
col1<-c(rep("first",2), rep("second",2), rep("third",2), rep("fourth",2), rep("fifth",2), rep("sixth",2), rep("seventh",2), rep("eighth",2))
col2<-gl(2,1,8, labels=c("one","two"))
col3<-Values
d1 <- data.frame(column1=col1, column2=col2, column3=col3)
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y=column3, fill=column2)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

The bars on my plot are in alphabetical order, but I need them to be in the order as in col1. How can I do this?

Comment: See this blog post: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/

Answer (score 1):

substitute:

```
d1 <- data.frame(column1=col1, column2=col2, column3=col3)
```

for:

```
d1 <- data.frame(column1=factor(col1, levels=unique(col1)), column2=col2, column3=col3)
```

the `factor(col1, levels=unique(col1))` akes a factor of `col1` and the `levels=` allows you to pick the order of the levels which will then be subsequently used by `ggplot` to define the order of your bars.